# Python variable concatenation for path?

Tags: python

I have several paths like:

```
 "/home/path1"

 "/home/path2"

 "/home/path3"
```

....

How can I represent all of them with one variable?

Like: `"/home/path[x]"`?

Comment: What do you mean by _represent_ here?

Comment: To generate a list of such paths, you could do this in a loop, `"/home/path{}".format(i)`. If you want a variable though, you could do `mypath="/home/path{}"`, then to assign a path number you can do `path_99=mypath.format(99)`

Comment: The shell allows you to specify a wildcard like `/home/path/path[123]` which you can expand with `glob.glob()` to find all matching, existing files. The Bash shell also has brace expansion like `/home/path/path{1,2,3}` but this is not portable to other shells or to Python's `glob.glob()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correct, probably would be two ways:

1. like @MJB mentioned:

```
    for x in range(0,100):
        path = "/home/path{}".format(i)
        print(path)
```

2. If you have array with the path it self:

```
    paths = ['path1', 'path2', 'path3']
    for x in paths:
        path = "/home/{}".format(x)
        print(path)
```

Comment: Thanks guys, this is exactly what I mean.